# Bessel filters: linear passband phase characteristic only for low pass filters?

Tags: filters, filter-design, continuous-signals

I've found a test (internet) from the contest to signal processing teacher and it has a question (true) or (false).

I cant find any book or paper to argue this statement. **Is it really true?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter types other than low pass (high pass, band pass, band stop) are obtained from a low pass prototype filter by frequency transformations (such as $s\rightarrow 1/s$ for a low pass / high pass transformation). These transformation destroy the optimality of the phase response. Nevertheless, filters obtained from a Bessel low pass prototype filter usually exhibit a passband phase response that is closer to a linear response than the phase response of the other standard filter types (Butterworth, Chebyshev, Cauer).